# Using filter function to generate missing data

Tags: matlab, octave

I have vectors of data that I feed through the filter() function -- said filter was constructed to emit a reasonable approximation of the original signal that is then used to identify "bad" elements in the original data (said elements are typically caused by infrequent short-duration sensor malfunctions and are quite distinct from good data).  After identifying these bad elements, I want to go back and replace them with something reasonable.

One approach would be to replace the bad values with the filtered output; however, the output was generated with the bad values, so it has some amount of undesired distortion.

Ideally, I'd like a way to tell filter() to assume that the bad element[s] are missing and that it should instead generate a reasonable interpolation of the missing value[s] (e.g., based on the surrounding values and the properties of the filter) for use when constructing the output.

I've been told that certain toolboxes allow insertion of special values (e.g., *NaN*) to indicate missing (but assumed to be well-behaved) data.

I looked at the source code for Octave's filter() and nothing obvious leapt out at me -- is there a special value (or other mechanism) to tell filter() to assume that well-behaved data is missing (and should be inserted as needed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inserting `NaN` won't work for this.  The `filter` function is pretty simple--it simply implements an IIR filter.

If your signal is smooth and slowly-changing, you might get away with simply using `interp1` to interpolate new values for the bad stretches based on the good data on either side.

If your signal has more complicated spectral content, I think "Wiener interpolation" is the phase to google for.   For *extrapolation* you can use [linear predictive coding](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/lpc.html).